# How to install CGAL in anaconda python 2.7 windows

Tags: python-2.7, cgal

I have lookimg foward a cgal library compatible as python 2.7 on windows 10 64bits. 
But I got this error for more than one sources of cgal

```
E:\CMSCODE>conda install -c salilab cgal=4.9.1
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - cgal 4.9.1* -> python 3.6*
  - python 2.7*
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that the package you are trying to install need python 3.6 but you have in your computer python 2.7. You can try to find the cgal compatible with your python version